# Good alternatives for mailchimp's css inliner tool?

Tags: gratis, email, css, web-apis, marketing

Recently, for a newsletter, I needed to fine-tune the HTML of an HTML Mail.
At some point during my work I had to convert formatting based on an external stylesheet to  inline styles.

I've used the free [CSS Inliner Tool](https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/) by Mailchimp.com for this task.

> Some email clients strip out `<head>` and `<style>` tags from emails, so it's best to have your CSS written inline within your markup. We know that writing inline CSS is time consuming and repetitive, so we've built this conversion tool to automatically inline your email's CSS.

It works very well.

But I wonder, if they decide to take this service offline, or start to charge for it, or change the functionality, what would be a good free alternative?

Can be another online service, or a desktop tool - command-line or GUI-based, I don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

Recently I have installed the free NodeJS-based command-line tool
[Juice](https://github.com/Automattic/juice) (github, >2.4 k stars)

> Given HTML, juice will inline your CSS properties into the style attribute.

Juice generates output that differs only marginally from the output of the MailChimp CSS inliner tool.

Now I use a purely command-line based workflow for converting documents